# how to change touches with changedtouches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code which moves a gif on html screen using two touch fingers

```
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
var $img = $('<img/>').attr({
  'id': 'cursor',
  'src': 'skin1.gif'
});
    $(document).on('touchstart touchmove ', function (e) {


      var touch1 = e.originalEvent.touches["0"];
      var touch2 = e.originalEvent.touches["1"];


      $img.css({
        top: (touch1.clientY+touch2.clientY)/2  - 105,
        left:  (touch1.clientX+touch2.clientX)/2 - 25,
        display: 'block'
      });

    });

$img.appendTo('body');
</script>
```

now i need to try changedTouches instead of  two var for each finger
and i tried this and it is not working

```
    <script id="jsbin-javascript">
    var $img = $('<img/>').attr({
      'id': 'cursor',
      'src': 'skin1.gif'
    });
        $(document).on('touchstart touchmove ', function (e) {



  var touches = e.originalEvent.changedTouches;


  $img.css({
    top: (touches["0"].clientY+touches["1"].clientY)/2  - 105,
    left:  (touches["0"].clientX+touches["1"].clientX)/2 - 25,
    display: 'block'
  });

});

    $img.appendTo('body');
    </script>
```

any help please 
thanks

Comment: The first uses `e.originalEvent.touches`, the second uses `e.originalEvent.changedTouches`... the second one is likely to not be defined.

Comment: how to fix the second one?

Comment: What error you have in console? Because everything look right.

Comment: Make sure `e.originalEvent.changedTouches`, is not undefined